# How to make 2nd level submenu work with Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know Bootstrap 3 doesn't support 2nd level submenus. Is there any way I can get around this in Wordpress?

My website is at http://www.csidb.com/stage . I'm referring to the menu at the top of the page.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/1004312

Comment: I saw that answer and tried implementing it. I'm having a hard time adding that class to Wordpress. Any ideas? Edit: When I add that class via the inspect element tool, it doesn't pull the second level. In fact, the second level isn't even rendering in HTML when I have created it in the Menu section of Wordpress