# Mobile multi-level (3) menu with bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help with multi-level menu build on bootstrap 3. I found on stack some examples how to build 3 level navigation menu, and all work ok but only on desktop - on mobile devices they don't... The menu which i'm trying to build will be used only on mobile - that why I'm need some help.

Here is my bootstrap code:

```
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TITLE</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">KOLECTION</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">PRODUCTS <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">STUFF 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a href="#">Product one</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Product two</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">STUFF 2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">STUFF 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't get it to work in desktop mode, either: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yL6g2/

Comment: You have to shrink the column

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing

Comment: You have right - I have to consider Blazemonger example. Thanks!