# Is it possible to have several levels sub-menus using bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu which has 3 levels, using bootstrap 3. Any suggestions how to do it or any suggestions of a tutorial would be appreciated.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!--<li><a href="http://www.wsnippets.com">Home</a></li>-->
                <li class="dropdown menu-large" >
              <a href=" #" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    User <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                    <ul class='dropdown-menu list-inline'>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                Year <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

```
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```