# angularjs: uib dropdown submenu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody suggest what I am missing in below html to add submenu to bootstrap dropdown?

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
  <button id="split-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
    <li><a ui-sref="a">a</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="b">b</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="c">c</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="d">d</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">e</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a ui-sref="e1">e1 (sub of e)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

Added [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pI33DPrgtUJSeGpgqsHW?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957038/angular-ui-multi-level-dropdown-toggle. Also see: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2421

Answer (score 0):

Because uibDropDown directive restricted to attribute.

You should write

```
<ul uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
```