# submenu in navbar twitter bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I switched from `twiiter bootstrap 2.3.2` to `3.1.1`. I need to display `submenu` but `3.1.1` does not provide this support. Is there any other way to get it using `twitter bootstrap v3.1.1`.

[image: submenu]

I need to `submenu using v3.1.1`.

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing