# Angular DropDown submenu

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I would like to make an angular dropdown menu which has basically the following tree.

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
   Option 3.1
   Option 3.2
   Option 3.3
Option 4
```

Each option should have a value , eg `"value="219"`

Any help or tips would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Bootstrap dropdowns.  Support may be somewhat deprecated, but people have ways of adding it back.  Checkout this thread, [Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

You can also can show the sub menu on hover if you want using things like Cameron's great Hover package, https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown