# Bootstrap all submenu open at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, submenu

I have a navbar which containing sub-menu. Once i hover over any top level menu item all sub-menu under this item open at the same time.

[image: All sub-menu are open]

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say you might have a 'li:hover ul' style when it should probably be 'li:hover > ul'

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't natively support drop-down menus on hover so the error you're having must be related to your implementation of showing the menus on hover. Please show what your implementation is.

Comment: @Evan I will check that

Comment: @Evan you are right. Thanks Evan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and say you might have a 'li:hover ul' style when it should probably be 'li:hover > ul'

Answer (score 1):

Submenus have been officially removed from Bootstrap 3. See the similar question below for more help on implementing this functionality yourself.

[Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/1669860)