# RTL support for bootstrap 3 submenus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem adjusting drop down sub menus to open to the right side (the software layout is in Hebrew).

I saw similar answers with providing external libraries, I don't want to do that. I want simply twick my css a bit so it will work ,I'm almost there, this is where you can help me :)

Those 2 pictures illustrate the issues I'm experiencing:

[image: caret size position and location]
[image: submenu overlaps with main]

I have three problems:

1. change caret position to the left
2. change caret location to the left
3. open submenu to the left side (right now it opens to the left but overlaps with the main one, but I can live with that, the above 2 are much more important)

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing), it is mentioned that bootstrap 3 doesn't support sub menus no more, I'm controlling it at my css.

**

- html

**:

```
<div ng-show="buildings.total_buildings" tooltip="מגוון פעולות שניתן לבצע על הרשומות שבחרתם" class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-building "></i>
        <span class="caret"></span> 
        <span class="badge_success badge">{{buildings.total_buildings}}</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="buildings.user.exportHtmlTableToPdf('buildings_table', 'lskd')"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;יצא לקובץ pdf</a>
        </li>   

        <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;שלח מייל</a>
            <ul href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;כולם</a>
                </li>                               
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-building owner"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;בעלים</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-building renter"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;שוכרים</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-building defecto"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;דיירים</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="return"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;שלח סמס</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="return"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;שלח מייל</a>
        </li>                       
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="buildings.showBuildingsData()"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;הצג דיירים</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="return"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;קרא וטען נתונים</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="return"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;מחק </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**

- CSS

**:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: right !important;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    right: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle using your code and it seems to be looking fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jan6wr5b/4/. Are you using any other styles as well?

Comment: Thanks Fahad, I've updated the fiddle with my whole css and added a dir="rtl" to the drop down menu, now it reproduces.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jan6wr5b/21/)**. I've made a few changes to your CSS and added some new styles:

```
.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    float: right;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 190px;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    text-align: right;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:before {
    content:'◄';
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Hi, everything should be right to left and in this fiddle everything is left to right