# How can I have a dropdown submenu with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a submenu inside "The best movies by genre" but it's now working

http://www.bootply.com/y1aWXXwQDR

How can I put the links (action, thriller, comedy..) as a submenu?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'submenu'?  Do you want a right popover kind of thing?  Or do you want something like an accordion?

Comment: @rogue_js i want to make it just like the parent dropdown. when you click it another submenu opens on the right side with more options

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstrap 3, this is a little tricky. I found [this resource](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) which provides a good example by including a chunk of extra CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

The HTML to use this code is pretty intuitive:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a href="#">Even More..</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here it is as a JsFiddle for forking and re-use: http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/9vkbgp74/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
$(function() {
  $('#byGenre').popover({
    content: $('#genres').html(),
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any difference. There is no submenu

Comment: Yea, that was my bad, the boootstrap fiddle didn't save