# GwtBootstrap3 NavBar with submenu

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I'm starting to use the GWTBoostrap3 and my greatest need is to create a menu that contains submenus, and this menu needs to be dynamic, so need to do in Java. It would be something like [Gwt MenuBar](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar)

my attempts....

```
final ListDropDown listDropDown = new ListDropDown();
AnchorButton anchorButton = new AnchorButton(ButtonType.INFO);
anchorButton.setText("btn1");
DropDownMenu dropDownMenu = new DropDownMenu();
AnchorListItem anchorListItemd = new AnchorListItem("Item 1");
dropDownMenu.add(anchorListItemd);
anchorButton.setDataToggle(Toggle.DROPDOWN);
listDropDown.add(anchorButton);
listDropDown.add(dropDownMenu);


final ListDropDown listDropDown2 = new ListDropDown();
final AnchorButton anchorButton2 = new AnchorButton(ButtonType.INFO);
anchorButton2.setText("Item 2");
DropDownMenu dropDownMenu2 = new DropDownMenu();
dropDownMenu2.setStyleName("dropdown-submenu");
dropDownMenu2.add(new AnchorListItem("Item 1"));
HTML child = new HTML();
child.addStyleName("caret");
anchorButton2.add(child);
anchorButton2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        anchorButton2.removeStyleName("dropdown-toggle");
        listDropDown.addStyleName("open");
        if(!listDropDown2.getStyleName().contains("open")){
            listDropDown2.addStyleName("open");                 
        }else{
            listDropDown2.removeStyleName("open");
        }

    }
});
listDropDown2.add(anchorButton2);
anchorButton2.removeStyleName("dropdown-toggle");
listDropDown2.add(dropDownMenu2);


dropDownMenu.add(listDropDown2);
```

Comment: Please provide more information what are you trying to do.

Comment: I created a normal menu, where a menu item is a listDropDown and within that listDropDown I put listDropDown2, but when you click to expand the 2nd listDropDown it does not expand it, and closes the 1st listDropDown. My attempt was to set manually onclick to change the css class to "dropdown open"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 [does not support submenus](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342). This is because Bootstrap 3 is a mobile first framework and submenus don't make sense on mobile.

If you still want to use submenus, you can [easily add them yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18023493/181497). You'll have to add the CSS referenced there somewhere in your app where it will be included and create a `DropDownSubmenu` widget, very similar to `DropDownMenu`, but using the style `dropdown-submenu`, instead of `dropdown-menu`.