# Multilevel Boostrap Menu in Yii 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I want my menu to have more than 2 levels. Looks like Yii 2 only renders up to 2 levels. For example this:

```
NavBar::begin();

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Level 1',
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Level 2 - 1', 'url' => '#'],
                ['label' => 'Level 2 - 2', 'url' => '#'],
                [
                    'label' => 'Level 2 - 3',
                    'items' => [
                        ['label' => 'Level 3 - 1', 'url' => '#'],
                        ['label' => 'Level 3 - 2', 'url' => '#'],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ],
]);

NavBar::end();
```

will not display the Level 3 - x menu items. How do I add more levels to the menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Yii 2 limitation, it's Boostrap 3 limitation.

Here is quote from **mdo** (one of the main Boostrap 3 contributors):

> We haven't seen anyone using submenus in meaningful ways and the code
>   necessary to make them work well is just too much overhead. Submenus
>   just don't have much of a place on the web right now, especially the
>   mobile web. They will be removed with 3.0.

It's taken from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342).

However you can find some alternatives to use more levels. For example take a look this [extension](https://github.com/fontenele/bootstrap-navbar-dropdowns).

Also this question is discussed with more details and examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing).

Answer (score 1):

1) Add Css in /web/css/site.css

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

2) Add submenu and attributes 'itemsOptions' , 'submenuOptions', 'items':

```
...
[
   'label' => 'Level 2 - 3',
   'itemsOptions'=>['class'=>'dropdown-submenu'],
   'submenuOptions'=>['class'=>'dropdown-menu'],
   'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Level 3 - 1', 'url' => '#'],
        ['label' => 'Level 3 - 2', 'url' => '#'],
    ],
],
....
```

3) ok !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this extension](http://demos.krajee.com/nav-x) of `Nav` widget.