# Bootstrap navigation bar menu item overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I am using Bootstrap and bootsnip's css http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/rVnKg in navigation bar.

Here is JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/ask1987/8xc7fk43/

Please check the JSFiddle link

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">ActionActi onActionA ction</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>      
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is menu items are overflowing when navbar-right class is used on ul element.

If it is set to left, navigation bar works just fine.

Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this class

```
class="collapse navbar-collapse"
```

Any how it is used to Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling ,where you are not using it any where.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KHtU4/14/)  and refer [Bootstrap Navabar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)  for more details.

Comment: I am using chrome. I don't see "action .... " text displayed in your working example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/3464552 refer this link we had already discussion on submenus @user3564816