# Bootstrap submenu on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Note**: Donot mark it as duplicate because I want only solution that uses no additional JS and/or css !!

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I know from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing) that the `.dropdown-submenu` has been removed in Bootstrap 3 RC

I checked [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreasPizsa/NzvKC/) too ... I want similar menu like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreasPizsa/NzvKC/) but **Without** any additional JS !! Is there any want to get `:hover` effect in my menu without adding any JS like above link ?? I just want to use pure Bootstrap 3 classes.

I tried, but it is not working as expected !!

```
                   <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right margin-bottom-half-em">
                        <li class="aboutus dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark-gray">
                              <li><a href="#" class="overview">Overview</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#" class="ourTeam">Our Team</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#" class="ourMission">Our Missions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>....
```

Comment: you might want to look into transitions http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzvKC/763/

You can use the `:hover` on the `<a>` and `<ul>` Tag to show the dropdown:

```
a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu,
ul.dropdown-menu:hover { display: block; }
```

But you have to remove the 2px margin of the `.dropdown-menu` to not lose the :hover state when moving the mouse from the `<a>` to the `<ul>`

```
.dropdown-menu { margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned that I donot want to write additional CSS or JS ... Is there any pure Bootstrap 3 solution ??

Comment: Oh I thought you just don't want to add new classes. But I guess there is no bootstrap solution for something that's removed from bootstrap? So this 3 CSS lines are maybe one of the easiest ways to fix this.