# Multilevel Menu using Knockout JS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to make a multilevel menu using Knockout JS and Bootstrap, but I'm not sure how.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var Person = function (name, children) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children || []);
};

var PeopleModel = function () {
    this.people = ko.observableArray([
        new Person("Bob", [
            new Person("Jan"),
            new Person("Don", [
                new Person("Ted"),
                new Person("Ben", [
                    new Person("Joe", [
                        new Person("Ali"),
                        new Person("Ken")
                    ])
                ]),
                new Person("Doug")
            ])
        ]),
        new Person("Ann", [
            new Person("Eve"),
            new Person("Hal")
        ])
    ]);

    this.addChild = function (name, parentArray) {
        parentArray.push(new Person(name));
    };
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new PeopleModel());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="people" class="nav navbar-nav"
            data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', foreach: people }">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="personTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="css: { dropdown: children().length > 0 }">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, visible: children().length < 1"></a>

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
           data-bind="text: name, visible: children().length > 0" 
           data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
            data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', foreach: children }">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you put this in a fiddle and explain exactly what part you are having a problem with?

Comment: Inspecting items in Chrome debugger shows that the structure is in place. There's apparently something about the structure that Bootstrap doesn't like.

Comment: When I try on my computer I see the root values in array (Bob and Ann). Also I see the descendant values (Jan-Don and Eve-Hal). But I can not see other values under Don. You can see the fiddle but fiddle does not work properlly. http://jsfiddle.net/d3ks0dgh/7/

Comment: I found a fiddle that appears to accomplish what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MCNK8/3/

It may require you changing your structure slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:
You have a `text` binding on the anchor that is supposed to have a caret inside it. The `text` binding will overwrite all contents, which is why you get no caret. Instead:

```
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="visible: children().length > 0" 
       data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
```

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ks0dgh/8/).

I still don't get submenus, but the caret does indicate that the HTML knows about Don's children. [This example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) might help.

Officially, it looks like [submenus are unsupported in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing#answer-18024991).

Answer (score 4):

Thank you [@Roy J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j), I used the css link you posted.

Here's how I solved it:

```js
var Person = function (name, children, rootItems) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.children = ko.observableArray(children || []);
        this.rootItems = ko.observable(rootItems || false);
    };

    var PeopleModel = function () {
        this.people = ko.observableArray([
            new Person("Bob", [
                new Person("Jan"),
                new Person("Don", [
                    new Person("Ted"),
                    new Person("Ben", [
                        new Person("Joe", [
                            new Person("Ali"),
                            new Person("Ken")
                        ])
                    ]),
                    new Person("Doug")
                ])
            ], true),
            new Person("Ann", [
                new Person("Eve"),
                new Person("Hal")
            ], true)
        ]);

        this.addChild = function (name, parentArray) {
            parentArray.push(new Person(name));
        };
    };

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new PeopleModel());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
    .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
    .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
    .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
</style>

<div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="people" class="nav navbar-nav"
            data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', foreach: people }">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="personTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="visible: rootItems(), css: { dropdown: children().length > 0 }">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, visible: children().length < 1"></a>

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="visible: children().length > 0" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', foreach: children }"></ul>
    </li>

    <li data-bind="visible: rootItems() ? false : true, css: { 'dropdown-submenu': children().length > 0 }">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, visible: children().length < 1"></a>

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="visible: children().length > 0" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', foreach: children }"></ul>
    </li> 
</script>
```