# Submenu does not work in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create a very simple dropdown with sub level items in bootstrap 3 as below.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">File</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Utilities<span class="pull-right">&raquo;</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>Item1</li>
                                <li>Item2</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I already include bootstrap.css, jquery.js adn bootstrap.js already. For the first level it works fine, but the second level does not work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3.x doesn't support dropdown submenus. You can achieve it by adding more css styles.

Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/5488620 
It may help you.