# Can't put submenu dropdown to the right using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, submenu, dropdown

I am creating a navigation bar for my website. One of the items has a sub-sub-menu and for some reasons, it is always expanded and it hides the rest of the sub-menu as it drops down and I can't manage to make it drop to the right side.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Nos Projets <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Soutien à nos familles parrainées</li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="bourse.php">Bouse d'étude universitaire</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="habitat.php">Amélioration de l'habitat</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Autres projets</li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Construction d'écoles <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="meovac2.php">Meo-Vac 2015-2016</a></li>
                <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="meovac.php">Meo-Vac 2013-2014</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="phuctue.php">Phuc Tue</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="bluedragon.php">Blue Dragon</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="sob.php">School on the Boat</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="archives.php">Archives</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have used the dropdown-menu-right but that doesn't seem to do anything.
Any advice on how to make it drop on the right?

Comment: this might helper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In currently, the `.dropdown-menu` has some style rules that make it stay at left include:

```
left: 0;
float: left;
```

You need to override those rules to have dropdown to right. Example:

```
left: auto;
right: 0;
float: right;
```