# Sub menu not displayed correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, submenu

i use bootstrap 3 and i try to display a button group with a submenu.
i use bootstrap-submenu

i created the menu

http://jsfiddle.net/L8kbaqw3/

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Actions</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu="" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a tabindex="0">Annuler</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="0">Sauvegarder</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="0">Payer</a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="0">Comptant</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="0">Débit</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="0">Carte de crédit</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="0">Carte cadeaux</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="0">Chèque</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

that work fine.

but when i try to add something under it, i don't see all the menu
http://jsfiddle.net/hxnznnz6/

it's seem like something block it to display completly the menu.

Also if you compare the layout of the two button, it's different

**Edit**
i removed the first  btn-group like @Eduardo Arruda Pimentel said.

look ok, but the sub menu of Payer is not displayed when i click on it

[image: submenu]

New result
http://jsfiddle.net/wn9u5z28/

Answer (score 1):

1)Bootstrap 3 removed  support for multilevel dropdowns, citing usability issues as the cause. As you can see in these two links:

[Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

[Responsive multilevel menu with Bootstrap 3](http://www.monolinea.com/responsive-multilevel-menu-with-bootstrap-3/)

2) The reason for the different layout is that the code is different. To solve that, just recode and delete this part of line 3:

```
class="btn-group"
```

Comment: menu is not displayed corectly, i posted an image who show the problem

Comment: I tested again, in my work. Menu is displaying correctly. What browser are you using?

Comment: firefox, ie and chrome... when i click on Payer item... nothing is displayed like the picture show

Comment: Your fiddle ia normal to me. Even in my cellphone.

Comment: what do you see in the Payer submenu?

Comment: tried under windows 7 ie/chrome/firefox, linux with firefox, chrome don't work surely a bug

Comment: Please make sure your fiddle is identical your real code. I will post a images as soon as possible. Not now because i'm using my cellphone to post.

Comment: Posted the image on answer...see, it's normal. Try in another pc. I tested in home (windows 10), work (windows 7) and mobile (iphone 4s).

Comment: that work like that... if you increase screen size of the table.. you should get the problem..

Comment: What is your screen size?

Comment: tested on 32", 27", 22"