# Create multi level dropdown-menu with Bootstrap3

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm building my `Django website` and I have questions about this process : `dropdown-menu` from `BootStrap3`.

I created `dropdown-menu` in my `navbar` and it works perfectly well. But, as I have some tabs, I would like to concatanate someone and get **dropdown-menu inside an existing dropdown-menu**.

I have already this kind of things :

[image]

With this kind of script (for example Fiches Individuelles tab) :

```
        <!-- Individual form tab -->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class = "dropdown">
                <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Fiches Individuelles
                <b class = "caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href = "{% url "home" %}"> Accueil des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url "form" %}"> Création des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url "searched" %}"> Consultation des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url "edited" %}"> Edition des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url "deleted" %}"> Suppression des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

And now it's a representation from what I want to get finally :

[image]

I want to get a dropdown-menu from an existing dropdown-menu.

I tried to write something :

```
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="accueil">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Fiches individuelles</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url "home" %}">Accueil des fiches individuelles</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
            </li>
```

But none effects for the moment :/

Have you idea or advices in order to help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Add the class `dropdown-submenu` to the li element and see if it works.... I'm not sure if it's still supported, but it was in bootstrap 2.3

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I tried to use submenu as my script try above. But doesn't work :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)