# Bootstrap 4: Multilevel Dropdown Inside Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What's the easiest way to make a multilevel dropdown in Bootstrap 4? All the examples I managed to find on SO were either too messy or not included in nav.

I've tried just placing a dropdown inside a dropdown, but that doesn't seem like it's working. Can someone help me with this one?

Here's the basic outline of my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems like that's working for me. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: You mean it's working when you just include dropdown inside a dropdown? @MichaelCoker

Comment: I mean the code you posted seems to work as expected. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @MichaelCoker It does, on a mobile version yeah. But try opening the snipped in full screen. I need the multilevel dropdown on there.

Comment: Still not sure what the problem is. The dropdown works when the navbar is visible in full-screen, too.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I need a dropdown inside a dropdown. So when they open a first dropdown and hover over a link inside it, another dropdown appears. Like a second level. Sorry if I didn't explain that well enough.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I think you should just write your own. according to Mark Otto, "Nested dropdowns aren't supported and haven't been since v3." https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21026

Comment: Bootstrap should have included this function by default.

Comment: @Retros Could you please check this out with `Bootstrap-5` https://stackoverflow.com/q/66092625/13919505 does not working with `Bootstrap-5` does not closing the sidenav on clicking another nav-dropdown

Comment: @Retros either the above link or this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/66098848/13919505 please check out, there are thousands of devs facing this issue with Bootstrap 5, not working well with multiple dropdown

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I use the following piece of CSS and JavaScript. It uses an extra class `dropdown-submenu`. I tested it with Bootstrap 4 beta.

It supports multi level sub menus.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
  });


  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I had to add **!important** to the top and left properties in the **.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu** CSS block to get my submenus aligned properly.

Comment: How to make animated submenu like slideUp, slideDown with this script?

Comment: how can i do second ul and other all ul menus side by side same height ? 
at the same height as the first submenu ?

Comment: @Gerhard Götz   Second level dropdown is not working for me.That is when i am clicking  *Submenu* link, the page just navigates to *localhost:4200/#*..please give solution

Comment: @Gerhard Götz I found the issue .I missed the jquery code in my code.When i  pasted the code,it is working fine..But is there any built in method from bootstrap for this multilevel dropdown ?

Comment: There is none. Therefore this solution. As far as i remember, the bootstrap developers think that multilevel dropdowns are not a good ui design. But in my opinion there are cases where multilevel dropdowns are ok.

Comment: how can i use above code on mouseover and leave, instead of click. I replaced the `click` with `mouseover` and replaced the `hidden.bs.dropdown` with `mouseleave`. but in this case, only fist level of dropdown working fine, next layer kept their even on mouseleave event. If someone got what i want to say than please guide me, Sry for my poor english

Answer (score 25):

The following is MultiLevel dropdown based on bootstrap4. I tried it was according to the bootstrap4 basic dropdown.

```css
.dropdown-submenu{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu a::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 40%;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown-menu{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu{
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It works well, but instead of `@media (max-width: 992px) { .dropdown-menu { width: 50%;` I used `display: inline-block;`.  The 50% width messes things up with long labels.

Comment: I like this one because it doesn't use any javascript. But found a bug! set left to important because it looks like the javascript in Bootstrap changes it after you click on an item. 
`left: 100%!important;`

Comment: Top also `top: 100%!important;`

Comment: How can I insert one more level in this menu?

Comment: @RodrigoZem just restrict the dropdown to be only for immediate children like this: `.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus > .dropdown-menu{` 

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059026/how-to-add-3rd-level-to-this-multi-level-bootstrap-dropdown/73066065#73066065) for a full example.

Answer (score 24):

***Updated 2018***

Here is another variation on the **Bootstrap 4.1** Navbar with multi-level dropdown. This one uses minimal CSS for the submenu, and can be re-positioned as desired:

[image]

https://codeply.com/go/nG6iMAmI2X

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

jQuery to control display of submenus:

```
$('.dropdown-submenu > a').on("click", function(e) {
    var submenu = $(this);
    $('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
    submenu.next('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.dropdown').on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function() {
    // hide any open menus when parent closes
    $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
});
```

---

See this answer for activating the [Bootstrap 4 submenus on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/171456)

Also see: [Bootstrap dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing/18024991#18024991)

Comment: I'd throw in a `e.preventDefault();`, but otherwise it is great.

Answer (score 14):

I found this [multidrop-down menu](https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/resource/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-navbar/) which work great in all device.

Also, have [hover style](https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/resource/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-hover-navbar/)

It supports multi-level submenus with bootstrap 4.

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.navbar a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $el = $( this );
        var $parent = $( this ).offsetParent( ".dropdown-menu" );
        $( this ).parent( "li" ).toggleClass( 'show' );

        if ( !$parent.parent().hasClass( 'navbar-nav' ) ) {
            $el.next().css( { "top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4 } );
        }
        $( '.navbar-nav li.show' ).not( $( this ).parents( "li" ) ).removeClass( "show" );
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.btco-menu li > a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000;
}

.btco-menu .active a:focus,
.btco-menu li a:focus ,
.navbar > .show > a:focus{
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .show > .dropdown-toggle::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded btco-menu">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>

                            <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Mobile view does not looks good. https://github.com/bootstrapthemesco/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-navbar

Answer (score 8):

Using official HTML without adding extra CSS styles and classes, it's like native support.

Just add the following code:

```
$.fn.dropdown = (function() {
    var $bsDropdown = $.fn.dropdown;
    return function(config) {
        if (typeof config === 'string' && config === 'toggle') { // dropdown toggle trigged
            $('.has-child-dropdown-show').removeClass('has-child-dropdown-show');
            $(this).closest('.dropdown').parents('.dropdown').addClass('has-child-dropdown-show');
        }
        var ret = $bsDropdown.call($(this), config);
        $(this).off('click.bs.dropdown'); // Turn off dropdown.js click event, it will call 'this.toggle()' internal
        return ret;
    }
})();

$(function() {
    $('.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).dropdown('toggle');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
        if ($(this).is('.has-child-dropdown-show')) {
            $(this).removeClass('has-child-dropdown-show');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Dropdown of bootstrap can be easily changed to infinite level. It's a pity that they didn't do it.

BTW, a hover version: https://github.com/dallaslu/bootstrap-4-multi-level-dropdown

Here is a perfect demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dallaslu/adky6jvs/ (works well with Bootstrap v4.4.1)

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly for me with Bootstrap 4.5. No custom CSS needed! I modified the jsfiddle demo to suit my needs.

Answer (score 5):

This one works on **Bootstrap 4.3.1**.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ko6L31w4/1/

The HTML code might be a little bit messy because I create a slightly complex dropdown menu for comprehensive test, otherwise everything is pretty straight forward.

Js includes fewer ways to collapse opened dropdowns and CSS only includes minimal styles for full functionalities.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle='dropdown']").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    //method 1: remove show from sibilings and their children under your first parent
    
/*   if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
        
          $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
       }  */     
     
     
    //method 2: remove show from all siblings of all your parents
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-submenu').siblings().find('.show').removeClass("show");
    
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("show");
    
    
    //collapse all after nav is closed
    $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
      $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white py-3 shadow-sm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold">Multilevel Dropdown</a>
    
  <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      
        <!-- nav dropdown -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some action</a></li>
            
            <!-- lvl 1 dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                
                <!-- lvl 2 dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                    
                    <!-- lvl 3 dropdown --> 
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 3</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 4</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some other action</a></li>
            
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>  
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. I'm using bootstrap 5 but i think it works also on bootstrap 4. You have to use "btn-group" class instead of "nav-item" class. And you don't have to code anything in jquery or create classes!. Check this snippet.

IMPORTANT: It seems better on full page!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-primary bg-gradient">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                

                
        <li class="btn-group">
          <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
            Clickable inside
          </div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="btn-group dropend">
                <button class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                  Clickable inside
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-group">
          <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
            Clickable inside
          </div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="btn-group dropend">
                <button class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                  Clickable inside
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer from Carol Skelly (https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/carol-skelly)

I updated the navbar with a few ids to allow submenus to be closed if clicked a second time

updated nav html section

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a href="#" id="menu" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
      data-display="static">Dropdown</a>
   <ul id="parentUL" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li id="subMenu1" class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
         <a id="subMenu1link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Submenu-1</a>
         <ul id="dropdownmenu1" class="dropdown-menu subUL">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-3</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="subMenu2" class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Submenu-2</a>
         <ul id="dropdownmenu2" class="dropdown-menu subUL">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#">Item-3</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Updated JQuery

```
$('.dropdown-submenu > a').on("click", function(e) {
        var submenu = $(this);
        var parentLI = submenu.parent().attr('id');
        var currentlyShowing = $('.subUL.show').parent().attr('id');
        if(parentLI == currentlyShowing){
            $('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
        } else {
            $('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
            submenu.next('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.dropdown').on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function() {
        // hide any open menus when parent closes
        $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
    });
```