# Bootstrap 4 Multi dropdown nav toggle issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a drop-down menu which works with bootstrap 4 alpha. But it's not working in bootstrap 4 beta.

When I click on the 2nd dropdown menu it closes automatically. But it was working fine before.

I've tried change the div with a `ul` dropdown inside a drop-down, but that doesn't work in beta version but it was working fine in alpha. Can someone help me with this one?

Here is the [**jsfiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/mu9h0tsx/1/)

Here's the dropdown link code structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Javascript**

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.navbar a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $el = $( this );
        var $parent = $( this ).offsetParent( ".dropdown-menu" );
        $( this ).parent( "li" ).toggleClass( 'show' );

        if ( !$parent.parent().hasClass( 'navbar-nav' ) ) {
            $el.next().css( { "top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4 } );
        }
        $( '.navbar-nav li.show' ).not( $( this ).parents( "li" ) ).removeClass( "show" );
        return true;
    } );
});
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.btco-menu li > a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000;

}

.btco-menu .active a:focus,
.btco-menu li a:focus ,
.navbar > .show > a:focus{
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
}


.dropdown-menu .show > .dropdown-toggle::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4: Multilevel Dropdown Inside Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation)

Comment: @ZivWeissman That also not working in bootstrap beta

Comment: I took the css + js only from that post, into your code (and added the submenu class) and it works. https://jsfiddle.net/mu9h0tsx/2/

Comment: @ZivWeissman Thanks its working now :)

Comment: @ZivWeissman But there is an issue. if I close the menu and reopen again. still, all drop-down menu open in site. [Check this gif](https://d1ax1i5f2y3x71.cloudfront.net/items/3U2f2W01192H1F461g3r/Screen%20Recording%202017-12-04%20at%2001.37%20PM.gif)

Comment: Btw I have fixed my self. Thanks