# Bootstrap 4 nested dropdown?

Tags: bootstrap-4

What I am trying to do is if anyone click on arts then History sociology and geography submenu should show up. It should now appear when someone clicks on Arts.
https://jsfiddle.net/0e7jdfza/

I tried adding this code https://jsfiddle.net/w3zyLmgb/ in place of arts li and ul but it down work inside the dropdown though it works outside this dropdown menu

```
<!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <!-- Required meta tags -->
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

                <title>Hello, world!</title>
              </head>
              <body>        
    <div class="dropdown show">
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Streams
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Science</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commerce</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arts</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>History</li>
                        <li>Sociology</li>
                        <li>Geogrphy</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                 </div>


            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: This is not the answer, just an alternative solution https://www.tutlane.com/example/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-with-dividers-example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation) is kinda what you are looking for.

Your updated code with one of the suggestions given in there would look something like the example given.

(If you use Angular you could use [ngx-dropdowns](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) they have a solution for nested dropdowns)

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });


  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown show">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Streams
                  </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Science</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commerce</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Arts</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">History</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geography</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sociology</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To dropleft, modify `left:100%` to `right:100%` in css code

Answer (score 0):

In following code I use Django template `for loop` to loop over multiple drop-down data. This code generates 2 level dropdown, with second level dropping on left side:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown ">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        {% for campus in object_list %}
            <li class="dropdown-submenu dropleft">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="#">{{ campus.name }}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    {% for school in campus.school.all %}
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                               href="">{{ school.name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have some issues with the other answers as:

- Displaying the submenu on the left doesn't work well on mobile. Furthermore, as the position of the menu is dynamically calculated by `popper.js`, you need to do the same for the position of the submenu. Playing well on mobile is one of the important things of bootstrap, so don't throw that away.
- Requirement of extra javascript or css code, which is exactly what bootstrap is trying to avoid. Doing this inevitably leads to other problems and maintenance further down the line.

So my suggestion is not to use 'submenus' as you know them from desktops/laptops, but use other means of achieving the same without leaving the bootstrap paradigm:

- display a modal when clicking the 'arts' menu item
- implement the 'submenu' using accordion, as in the example below using bootstrap 5
- be creative!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown show title">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Streams
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu accordion" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" id="accordionParent">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Science</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commerce</a></li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <h4 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="[data-binding-id=artsItem]" aria-expanded="false">
          Arts
        </button>
      </h4>
    </li>
    <li class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionParent" data-binding-id="artsItem" role="presentation">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem">
        History
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionParent" data-binding-id="artsItem" role="presentation">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem">
        Sociology
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionParent" data-binding-id="artsItem" role="presentation">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem">
        Geography
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#type").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "arts") {
            $("#type").html("<option value='history'>history</option><option value='sociology'>sociology</option><option value='geography'>geography</option>");
        } else if (val == "science") {
            $("#type").html("<option value='maths'>maths</option><option value='physics'>physics</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <option value="na">--Select an Item--</option>
    <option value="arts">Arts</option>
    <option value="science">Science</option>
</select>
```