# How in dropdown menu add collapse submenu?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

how to add collapse menu in dropdown menu? When you click on the menu item collapse, dropdown menu closed. When you reopen the dropdown menu, the collapse works.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
 <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown link
 </a>

 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false"
   aria-controls="collapse" title="Description">Description
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
  </div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated. Check [bootstrap 4 multilevel dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation)

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I have a main menu, dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a bit of jquery to achieve that:

**Update:** Toggle `aria-expanded` attribute

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var dropToggle = $('.dropdown-menu > .dropdown-toggle');             
    // Click event
    dropToggle.click(function(e) {
        // Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
        e.stopPropagation();

        // New var 'expanded' to the check the 'aria-expanded' attribute
        var expanded = $(this).attr('aria-expanded');
        //  Inline if to set 'aria-expanded' to true if it was false
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded', expanded === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');
        // Show the next element which is your dropdown menu 
        $(this).next().toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropToggle = $('.dropdown-menu > .dropdown-toggle');
  // Click event
  dropToggle.click(function(e) {
    // Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
    e.stopPropagation();

    // New var 'expanded' to the check the 'aria-expanded' attribute
    var expanded = $(this).attr('aria-expanded');
    //  Inline if to set 'aria-expanded' to true if it was false
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', expanded === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');
    // Show the next element which is your dropdown menu 
    $(this).next().toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
a.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border-top: .3em solid;
  border-right: .3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}
a.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: .3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: .3em solid;
  border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">Dropdown link</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse" title="Description">Description</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
    </div>
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1" title="Description">Description</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
    </div>
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2" title="Description">Description</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="" title="Description">Description</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Please note that if you opened all the collapsed menus at the same time, sometimes the dropdown menu it self will jump out of its position which caused by `popper.js` auto placement. If you like to fix that, just add `data-display="static"` attribute to the first link that have `data-toggle="dropdown"` like in your case:

```html
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">Dropdown link</a>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what you need, but how to add aria-expanded = "false" when toggleClass ("collapse")?

Comment: @Jekis I've updated the code to add the `aria-expanded` toggle, added some comments to show how it works.

Comment: When I added a few collapse menus, when clicking on them, the dropdown-toggle arrow does not work correctly.

Comment: @Jekis Updated again, I guess it works ok now please check it.

Comment: Hello friend, how can remove anchor (#collapse)?

Comment: Hi there, sorry, i didn't understand, you mean `href="#collapse"` ? you can delete it, bootstrap uses `aria-controls` attribute to select the ID to open it. like so: `aria-controls="collapse1"` will target `id="collapse1"`

Comment: No, I meant to remove the anchor and all that comes after it. (href="http://www.example.com/#collapse") -> (href="http://www.example.com/")

Comment: Yes, that was my point. just remove the whole `href="#collapse"` from all `dropdown-toggle` links then manually remove the `#collaose` from your `"example.com/#collapse")` link because it will be saved, refresh the page. Example [here](https://codepen.io/awran5/pen/RdzPgM)