# Prevent dropdown from closing when pressing specific link / button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that has different elements inside, among these there are more dropdowns and buttons.

Initially this dropdown (menu) only had dropdowns (sub-menus) inside it, with the following structure. [It is from this post in its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation), I simply changed names and added or removed sub-menus based on my data.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
  });


  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The good thing that this code provides is that clicking on the sub-menu does not close everything, on the contrary, it opens the desired submenu.

**The problem is that the links inside the dropdown, close it. And I need change this.**

Reading in other posts I have seen that perhaps I should use `.stopPropagation()`, but the problem is that if I do that, the links no longer execute the subsequent functions that make said filtering.

I have thought about putting one more conditional in which it looks for a specific class that will give these special links that are not to be closed, for example `class = "filters-drop"` and here apply the `.stopPropagation()` but I don't It works and also breaks what was previously achieved.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
  });

  if ($(this).hasClass('filters-drop')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  return false;
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you very much, greetings and health to all.

Comment: I am having trouble understating desired behavior from your post. Please elaborate, or simplify.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, I edited trying simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case the dropdown is being closed because you have not mentioned any link or url inside it to be redirected to the next page and `.stopPropogation()` is not the option for the desired outcome instead you must prevent the default behaviour of the `anchor` tags in the last to li's as

First assign id's for both the `anchor` tags in the last dropdown as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id = 'first'>Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id = 'second'>Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And after assigning id's to prevent its default behaviour add a js as

```
<script>
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, thank for answering. But I'm trying it and I have the same behaviour yet. If I'm understanding correctly, you say I have to add the `id` to the links (as you have done) and add the `js` for example in my `html` code. :(

Comment: No... nothing is changing :(