# Jquery is not closing drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Dogs dropdown does not close clicking on Pet Cages]I was building, multi-level(only second level) dropdown with Bootstrap Navigation Bar. I could find One [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45755948/13919505) to build Multi-level dropdown.

[**JSFiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/dgsmith68/jyx6a8Lq/4/)

However, the drop-down is not closing on click. The dropdown can be closed by clicking in the `Document`, I have added below `jquery`.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
});
```

The drop-down closes, but, when clicked in other `nav-item` the opened dropdown does not closes. So, basic `JQuery` is missing by me.
Basically `show` class is not removing from `.dropdown-menu` class when clicked in other `nav-item`. So, I want to remove the `show` class from `.dropdown-menu`

**Edit :** I am looking for working `JS` or `Jquery` code, the above `Jquery` is broken code copied from the staoverflow. So, looking for complete and clean solution

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
      $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
    }
    var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
    $subMenu.toggleClass('show');
  
    return false;
  });

$(document).click(function() {
    //   $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
$('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
});

$('.dropdown').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .dropdown-submenu a::after {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: .8em;
  }
  
  .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: .1rem;
    margin-right: .1rem;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary py-1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="flex-row d-flex">         
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>    
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button> 
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dogs
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bulldog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Al</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Labrador</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Puppies</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky B</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky C</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Pet Products</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Amphibian</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Pet Cages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Pet Guides
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Labrador</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lizard</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      ML & AI
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pet CBD</a></li>                      
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <!-- <form class="d-flex"> -->
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button> -->
                  <!-- </form> -->
              </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: @user1735921 add `show` in the class list of the parent element `#navbarSupportedContent`

Comment: It closes for me when I click on other nav-item.

Comment: try in JSFiddle, if you are not using other editors

Comment: @munna01  Your complete set of example code right here in the question should fully reproduce your issue.  Testing in Chrome, this snippet seems to work as it stands here.  Please provide more details or specific information regarding your issue in that specific set of code as part of your actual question. (not the fiddle, this one here)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Please check, I have added gif screenshot(explaining the issue - "Dogs dropdown should close clicking on Pet Cages dropdown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the **MAIN PROBLEM OF PERSISTANT OPPENED DROPWON** , you can fix that problem by listening the `nav-link` event `show.bs.dropdown` and then remove the show class from the `.dropdown` wrapped by `.dropdown-submenu`

as folow :

```
$('.nav-link').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
});
```

See below working snippet : ( try it also in fullscreen )

For the sake of testing , I've rmoved some menu from snippet :

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');

  return false;
});


$('.nav-link').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
});

$(document).on("click", ".nav-link", function(e){
  console.log("clicl nav");
})

$('.dropdown').click(function(event) {
  console.log("click");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary py-1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-row d-flex">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dogs
                  </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bulldog</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Al</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Labrador</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Puppies</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky B</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky C</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Pet Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Amphibian</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Pet Cages
                    </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button> -->
        <!-- </form> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @munna01 , could you describe what you need exactly ? close dropdown once clicking outside ?

Comment: yes. clicking even other nav-link, should close previously opened nav(side-nav)s

Comment: Could you please look into - this issue, new question asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098848/bootstrap-4-dropdown-not-working-with-bootstrap-5

Comment: @munna01 , updated my answer , I think now I could understand your problem (after seen the screen record gif )

Comment: Was the error from my end that I could not write better to convince you. Maybe my English was not good(Is that the reason)

Comment: @munna01 , no , that's my fault , I was reading quickly, that's why I didn't take in consideration the real problem , but after coming back and seeing the image I understood my mistake :)

Comment: This answer was requested from another account, for "Voting Irregularities, maybe your account also" suspended. `$(document).click(function(event) {if ($(event.target).closest("nav.navbar").length === 0)$(".navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)").click();});` This part causing trouble, removed, removing this, also works fine. You you respond me in twitter, as account suspended

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `jQuery` to achieve this.
Remove `jQuery` and additional `javascript` code and your dropdown menu will work from adding a simple `css` code.

```css
        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -6px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu>a : after {
            display: block;
            content: " ";
            float: right;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
            border-left-color: #ccc;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu:hover > a : after {
            border-left-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
            float: none;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary py-1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="flex-row d-flex">         
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>    
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button> 
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dogs
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bulldog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Al</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Labrador</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Puppies</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky B</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Husky C</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Pet Products</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Amphibian</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Pet Cages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reptile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Pet Guides
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Labrador</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lizard</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      ML & AI
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pet CBD</a></li>                      
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <!-- <form class="d-flex"> -->
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button> -->
                  <!-- </form> -->
              </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Can not accept hover, this breaks site in Mobile.