# add multilevel dropdown bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add submenu for test which is under the pages but I can't any help please the dropmenu already worked with me but I want to apply sub-menu?

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="themes_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">pages</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes_dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">contact</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">test</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    <ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to add bootstrap files in your project first. You can follow [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for better understanding of **Bootstrap Navbar**.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul I think the OP knows about the Bootstrap libraries. He's asking about *nested dropdowns*

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation