# Bootstrap multilevel dropdown with expand

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

How to create multi level dropdown with expand so that each level can expand in the same dropdown box using bootstrap?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDXAX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4: Multilevel Dropdown Inside Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation)

Comment: no. In the above answer each dropdown and sub dropdown open in separate box with different height. What I want is each dropdown has same height and has only one parent box. Than parent box can expand when you open sub dropdown.