# how to add 3rd level to this multi-level bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I like the multilevel dropdown from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation/44846667#44846667) but can't figure out how to add extra sub levels to the menu. Can someone please show me how? When I add a new subsubmenu class copying this pattern it appears at the same time as the second level: [like this](https://i.ibb.co/jymDHhr/image.png).

css

```
.dropdown-submenu{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu a::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 40%;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown-menu{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu{
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix, just constrain the selector to its immediate child like this:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:focus > .dropdown-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 100%!important;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
 <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle mb-1" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Style
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Level 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Level 3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">c</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">d</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```