# Multi- level dropdown using BootStrap-4 navbar goes out of screen when dropsdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i just can't get this to work.I uses BS4 for responsiveness. my navs are right aligned in the navbar. I tried so many things to position the submenu at the left of the parent menu... but then it does not display submenu. the same problem arises when Sub-submenu dropdowns

HTML code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Style Sheets Attaches Here-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/multi-navbar.css">
    <!-- Style Sheets Ends Here-->

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <img src="assets/logo.jpg" class="rounded" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;NavBar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills nav-fill">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">menu1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">menu2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">menu1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">menu2/a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Another</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub-submenu1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub-submenu1</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu ">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">menu1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Yet Another</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1-submenu 1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1-submenu 2</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2-submenu 1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2-submenu 2</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar completed Here-->


    <!-- Javascript Loads Here-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS - multi-navbar.css

```
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;
}
/* rotate caret on hover */
.dropdown-menu >li > a:hover:after {
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

These are the codes i used other than Bootstrap-4
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parent dropdowns to `dropdown-menu-right` and the CSS to position the submenu on the left instead of right...

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top:0;left:-100%;margin-top:-6px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/DznMvv8PhP

Also make sure the HTML is properly structured (the code you posted is not).

Related: [Bootstrap 3 dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing/18024991#18024991)

Comment: I am a beginner in webpage, could you please clarify the problems in my HTML. Please