# Bootstrap 4 Multiple Level Nav Bar, How can I make it drop to the right on the 3rd layer?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, bootstrap-4

[clickable dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOL0E.jpg)

[hover dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlD4.jpg).jpg

Source:https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/resource/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-hover-navbar/

How can I achieve a menu that is drop to the right accordingly like the clickable dropdown nav. As the hover version of it is actually dropdown to the left which i want it to be position at the right.
I am alright with any other solutions but I need to use the latest bootstrap and jquery. Thanks.

```js
/*!
 * Bootstrap 4 multi dropdown navbar ( https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/resource/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-navbar/ )
 * Copyright 2017.
 * Licensed under the GPL license
 */


$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $el = $( this );
        var $parent = $( this ).offsetParent( ".dropdown-menu" );
        if ( !$( this ).next().hasClass( 'show' ) ) {
            $( this ).parents( '.dropdown-menu' ).first().find( '.show' ).removeClass( "show" );
        }
        var $subMenu = $( this ).next( ".dropdown-menu" );
        $subMenu.toggleClass( 'show' );
        
        $( this ).parent( "li" ).toggleClass( 'show' );

        $( this ).parents( 'li.nav-item.dropdown.show' ).on( 'hidden.bs.dropdown', function ( e ) {
            $( '.dropdown-menu .show' ).removeClass( "show" );
        } );
        
         if ( !$parent.parent().hasClass( 'navbar-nav' ) ) {
            $el.next().css( { "top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4 } );
        }

        return false;
    } );
} );
```

```css
/*=-====Bootstrapthemes.co btco-hover-menu=====*/

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.btco-hover-menu a ,  .navbar > li > a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.btco-hover-menu .active a,
.btco-hover-menu .active a:focus,
.btco-hover-menu .active a:hover,
.btco-hover-menu li a:hover,
.btco-hover-menu li a:focus ,
.navbar>.show>a,  .navbar>.show>a:focus,  .navbar>.show>a:hover{
    color: #000;
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
}



/*submenu style start from here*/


.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px 0; 
    margin: 0 0 0; 
    border: 0px solid transition !important;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15); 
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;

}

/*first level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul > li:hover > a{background: #f5f5f5;}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul > li:hover > a, .navbar .show .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .navbar .show .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{background: #fff;}
/*second level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul > li:hover > a{background: #fff;}

/*third level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5;}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5}

/*Drop-down menu work on hover*/
.btco-hover-menu{background: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;min-height:20px}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .btco-hover-menu .show > .dropdown-toggle::after{
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {

    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul li{position:relative;}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul li:hover> ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;min-width:250px;display:none}
    /*******/
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul li{position:relative}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul li:hover> ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:100%;min-width:250px;display:none}
    /*******/
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul li{position:relative}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul li:hover ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100%;min-width:250px;display:none;z-index:1}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 4 Navbar with hover multi dropdown</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="css/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--Demo purpose css-->
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
            .navbar {
                margin:  40px 0;
            }
            .jumbotron{background-color: #1f1f1f;color: #fff;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>




        <div class="container">

            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light btco-hover-menu">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action aa</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action bb</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action 2</a></li>


                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action 1 3</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action 2 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu 3</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action 3 </a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>



        </div> <!-- /container -->






        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.js"></script>
    

</body></html>
```

Comment: Your first image link is not valid.

Comment: hi, updated! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to **remove** 1 line in the CSS...

```
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100%;min-width:250px;display:none;z-index:1}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/EuirMfjkYZ

---

Also, the provided multi-level menu is unnecessarily complex. You can create the same effect with **simple CSS**: https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4  (no jQuery) as explained in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/171456).

[Hover version](https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4)
[Click version](https://www.codeply.com/go/nG6iMAmI2X)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I want

Comment: Hi, I realized that the nav-item's href is not working. For example: <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.google.com" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Hover
                </a> How can I get this links working on click of the navbar item "Hover"?

Comment: It does work. Look at the Google link here: https://www.codeply.com/render/ji5ijk6yJ4

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*=-====Bootstrapthemes.co btco-hover-menu=====*/

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.btco-hover-menu a ,  .navbar > li > a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.btco-hover-menu .active a,
.btco-hover-menu .active a:focus,
.btco-hover-menu .active a:hover,
.btco-hover-menu li a:hover,
.btco-hover-menu li a:focus ,
.navbar>.show>a,  .navbar>.show>a:focus,  .navbar>.show>a:hover{
    color: #000;
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
}



/*submenu style start from here*/


.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px 0; 
    margin: 0 0 0; 
    border: 0px solid transition !important;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);  
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;

}

/*first level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul > li:hover > a{background: #f5f5f5;}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul > li:hover > a, .navbar .show .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .navbar .show .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{background: #fff;}
/*second level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul > li:hover > a{background: #fff;}

/*third level*/
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5;}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5}
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul, .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul.dropdown-menu{background:#f5f5f5}

/*Drop-down menu work on hover*/
.btco-hover-menu{background: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;min-height:20px}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .btco-hover-menu .show > .dropdown-toggle::after{
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {

    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul li{position:relative;}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul li:hover> ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;min-width:250px;display:none}
    /*******/
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul li{position:relative}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul li:hover> ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:100%;min-width:250px;display:none}
    /*******/
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul li{position:relative}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul li:hover ul{display:block}
    .btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100%;min-width:250px;display:none;z-index:1}

}
```

```js
/*!
 * Bootstrap 4 multi dropdown navbar ( https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/resource/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-navbar/ )
 * Copyright 2017.
 * Licensed under the GPL license
 */


$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'mouseenter', function ( e ) {
        var $el = $( this );
        var $parent = $( this ).offsetParent( ".dropdown-menu" );
        if ( !$( this ).next().hasClass( 'show' ) ) {
            $( this ).parents( '.dropdown-menu' ).first().find( '.show' ).removeClass( "show" );
        }
        var subMenu = $( this ).next( ".dropdown-menu" );
        
        subMenu.css({'position': 'absolute', top: $el[0].offsetTop, left: $(this).width() + 50});
        subMenu.toggleClass( 'show' );
        
        $( this ).parent( "li" ).toggleClass( 'show' );

        $( this ).parents( 'li.nav-item.dropdown.show' ).on( 'hidden.bs.dropdown', function ( e ) {
            $( '.dropdown-menu .show' ).removeClass( "show" );
        } );
        
         if ( !$parent.parent().hasClass( 'navbar-nav' ) ) {
            $el.next().css( { "top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4 } );
        }

        return false;
    } );
    $( '.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'mouseleave', function ( e ) {
        var subMenu = $( this ).next( ".dropdown-menu" );
        subMenu.toggleClass( 'show' );
    });
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 4 Navbar with hover multi dropdown</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="css/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--Demo purpose css-->
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
            .navbar {
                margin:  40px 0;
            }
            .jumbotron{background-color: #1f1f1f;color: #fff;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>




        <div class="container">

            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light btco-hover-menu">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action aa</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action bb</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action 2</a></li>


                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action 1 3</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action 2 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu 3</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action 3 </a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>



        </div> <!-- /container -->






        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.js"></script>
    

</body></html>
```

Comment: let me know how it goes

Comment: this is the clickable version, i want it to be able to hover

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to override default :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px)
.btco-hover-menu .collapse ul ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
}
```