# bootstrap dropdown 3.3.7 submenu does not expand

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I pasted the code from [here](http://bootstrapessentials.com/fulldocs/components/navbar/navbar-submenu/) into my web application. It works except for the
`Service C` dropdown submenu. I can't see `Service C1` ... `Service C5`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">Services</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="nav-label">Service C</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Service C1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The page writes now:

```
The support for sub-menu was disabled in latest version of bootstrap. The option can be re-enabled by including a small CSS.
```

Do you know the CSS that is needed and where to put it?

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and would like not to change this version.

Comment: provided link is bootstrap 3x but tagged bootstrap 4x. what you are using actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i did some changes see it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">                                      
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">Services</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" href="#">Service C <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Service C1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service C5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

i just cloned the repo that you mentioned in comment and i pasted my code there and it's working fine look bellow i haven't updated anything

> in your project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <style>
        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

       .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
               margin-top: -1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="http://tech.trailmax.info" class="navbar-brand">tech.trailmax.info</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">Services</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" href="#">Service C <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Service C1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Service C2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Service C3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Service C4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Service C5</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).next('ul').toggle();
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

> look bellow image

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Without JavaScript snippet it would not work.

Comment: I just don't understand, why it doesn't work in [this](https://github.com/trailmax/OwinADAuthentication) project. When I paste the code [here](https://github.com/trailmax/OwinADAuthentication/blob/master/ActiveDirectoryAuthentication/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml). I updated bootstrap to 3.3.7 (with 3.3.6 it doesn't work at all). Version of Jquery shouldn't be a problem, as I noticed. It's really mysterious that it does not work here.

Comment: look your repo's attached layout page i just updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, it works now. It seems that the position of <scripts> plays role.

Answer (score 1):

`.dropdown-menu` has `display:none` property as you can see in [bootstrap css file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css). You can add easily a `display:block` class like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass("opened");
  });
});
```

```css
.opened {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">Services</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="nav-label">Service C</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Service C1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service C2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service C3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service C4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service C5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I prefer the first solution though, because after I click somewhere on the page, the drop-down tree will disappear.