# Submenus in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, submenu

Is there a way to have sub-menus in Bootstrap 3 ?

I can't find the Bootstrap 3 equivalent to this Bootstrap 2 sub-menus - https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns

```
<li class="dropdown open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Vehicles<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/audi">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bmw">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="/honda">Honda</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="/maruti">Maruti</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/suzuki">Suzuki</a></li>
                <li><a href="/suzuki">Suzuki</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)

Comment: It works well on desktop, but on mobile the functionality is missing. I don't get the mobile menu / sub-menu view.