# Is There an Offical Class for Bootstrap 3 for Dropdown Submenus?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using Bootstrap 3 are there official classes to use with a Dropdown to create a flyout or Submenu? Are there classes to create classes that drop up or are these generally custom classes?

Comment: It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing).

Answer (score 1):

did you think of this?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-dropdowns

but you can also use custom classes

Comment: I did, there are no examples of Submenus in Bootstrap's documentation for version 3. Same for a Drop Up.

Comment: try, this way: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: So you're saying with the code example that a Submenu isn't a part of Bootstrap's 3 classes and you've created your own class to demonstrate that, yes Submenus can be easily created in Bootstrap 3. But there isn't an official class to do so?