# Bootstrap 5 dropdown toggles wrong menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am building a site with Bootstrap 5.
My site contains a navbar with a dropdown menu that contains dropend menus.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="route-4" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Categories</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="route-4">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown-item dropdown dropend" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="route-5" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Category 1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="route-5">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Subcategory 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Subcategory 2</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown-item dropdown dropend" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="route-9" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Category 2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="route-9">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Subcategory 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Subcategory 2</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My problem is that every category toggler just toggles the first subcategory menu.
I have tried to use `data-bs-target` but is didn't change anything.

For context. I used npm to install bootstrap

Can someone help me?

Comment: You put `data-bs-target` on the wrong elements. It needs to go on the actual links, not their parent list item.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't support nested dropdowns. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing/18024991#18024991) for some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 doesn't require `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` and id attributes for nested dropdowns to work. Instead, the proper nesting and classes should handle the behavior correctly. However, for nested dropdowns to function as expected, each dropdown link **`<a>`** tag should directly toggle its own **`.dropdown-menu`**.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="categoriesDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Categories
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="categoriesDropdown">
      <!-- Category 1 Dropend -->
      <li class="dropdown dropend">
         <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="category1Dropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Category 1
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="category1Dropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subcategory 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subcategory 2</a></li>
            <!-- More subcategories as needed -->
         </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Category 2 Dropend -->
      <li class="dropdown dropend">
         <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="category2Dropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Category 2
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="category2Dropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subcategory 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subcategory 2</a></li>
            <!-- More subcategories as needed -->
         </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Add more categories as needed -->
   </ul>
</li>
```